# Validate method of AbstractValidator never is called using ValidatorFactoryBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac, fluentvalidation

I implemented my Validations using FluentValidation and Autofac.

The `CreateInstance` is called, but the method Validate of AbstractValidator not, so my model not is validate using my rules.

Debugging:
In `CreateInstance` the correct AbstractValidator is returned.

But I put breakpoints in `Validate` and not is called.

Any Ideia?

My code:

```
public class AutofacValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;

    public AutofacValidatorFactory(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        object instance;
        if (_context.TryResolve(validatorType, out instance))
        {
            var validator = instance as IValidator;
            return validator; //UsuarioCadastrarValidator is returned 
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class UsuarioCadastrarValidator : AbstractValidator<UsuarioCadastrarVM>
{
    public UsuarioCadastrarValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Nome).NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(a => a.Nome).Length(4, 200);

        ...
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(UsuarioCadastrarVM instance)
    {
        return base.Validate(instance); //breakpoint here not is called
    }

    public override IValidatorDescriptor CreateDescriptor()
    {
        return base.CreateDescriptor(); //breakpoint here IS called
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<UsuarioCadastrarVM> context)
    {
        return base.Validate(context); //breakpoint here not is called
    }

    public override Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<UsuarioCadastrarVM> context, CancellationToken cancellation = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return base.ValidateAsync(context, cancellation); //breakpoint here not is called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UsuarioCadastrarVM` I have a property `CargoId` with type `int`

The problem was `CargoId` is a integer, so the `MVC` is not able to bind my post to my ViewModel, because in my tests I sended a empty value, if I send a value to `CargoId` or change to nullable (`int?`) the validation works well.